# Plotting all subgroups - venn diagram

Tags: r, statistics, combinations

I've been dealing with R recently and I've come across an interesting problem. I have to plot all possible venn diagrams of 9 one-column datasets (let's name them df1...df9). I'm using library(gplots), and the piece of code for `venn` with an example input is:

```
venn(list(df1,df2,df3,df4))
```

The question is: how can I generate all possible subsets of those nine datasets (there are total of 126 - computed used combs function.), and export them in a list, which could be the inputted into venn. So for example:
(df1,df2),
(df5,df4),
(df3,df5,df8)
.
.
.
Here I would iterate through all options and plot the venn diagram for each.
Thank you for any hints.

Comment: You do realise that would give you 512 Venn diagrams, right? Are you sure that's what you want? Also, I don't know of any implementation that supports more than 5 sets. I remember answering a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559371/how-to-get-the-list-of-items-in-venn-diagram-in-r/23560500#23560500).

Comment: Yes, My aim wasnt to plot them all, just to get to know the method. And the answer provided was just perfect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with a reproducible example:

```
# Sample data (9 15-element subsets of the letters stored in a list)
set.seed(144)
(dfs <- replicate(9, sample(letters, 15), simplify=FALSE))
# [[1]]
#  [1] "b" "r" "y" "l" "g" "n" "a" "u" "z" "s" "j" "c" "h" "x" "m"
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] "b" "n" "m" "t" "i" "f" "a" "l" "k" "u" "o" "c" "g" "v" "p"
# ...
```

The `venn` function doesn't support venn diagrams with more than 5 sets, and venn diagrams with one set are pretty uninteresting. Therefore, I'll limit to subsets with two to five sets:

```
# Get all subsets with 2-5 elements
subs <- do.call(expand.grid, replicate(length(dfs), c(F, T), simplify=F))
subs <- subs[rowSums(subs) %in% 2:5,]
venns <- apply(subs, 1, function(x) venn(dfs[x], show.plot=F))
```

`venns` now contains all 372 of your venn diagram objects. You could plot a particular one with, for instance, `plot(venns[[100]])`

[image]

If you really wanted to plot all the venn diagrams, you might do something like:

```
apply(subs, 1, function(x) {
  png(paste0("venn_", paste(which(x), collapse="_"), ".png"))
  venn(dfs[x])
  dev.off()
})
```

This would create 372 image files containing the venn diagrams, named based on the sets that are included.

Comment: This is great, of course I dont need them all, but knowing how to do it is the key, this is awesome!