# How to obtain the list of elements from a Venn diagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have a Venn diagram made from 3 lists, I would like to obtain all the different sub-lists, common elements between two lists, between the tree of them, and the unique elements for each list. Is there a way to make this as straight forward as possible?

```
AW.DL <- c("a","b","c","d")

AW.FL <- c("a","b", "e", "f")

AW.UL <- c("a","c", "e", "g")

venn.diagram(
  x = list(AW.DL, AW.FL, AW.UL),
  category.names = c("AW.DL" , "AW.FL","AW.UL" ),
  filename = '#14_venn_diagramm.png',
  output=TRUE,
  na = "remove"
)
```

Comment: what package is the function `venn.diagram()` from?

Comment: Its from package VennDiagram

Comment: The base R function `setdiff()` can be helpful and pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the package `VennDiagram` has a function `calculate.overlap()` but I wasn't able to find a way to name the sections from this function. However, if you use package `gplots` , there is the function `venn()` which will return the intersections attribute.

```
AW.DL <- c("a","b","c","d")

AW.FL <- c("a","b", "e", "f")

AW.UL <- c("a","c", "e", "g")

library(gplots)

lst <- list(AW.DL,AW.FL,AW.UL)

ItemsList <- venn(lst, show.plot = FALSE)

lengths(attributes(ItemsList)$intersections)
```

Output:

```
> lengths(attributes(ItemsList)$intersections)
    A     B     C   A:B   A:C   B:C A:B:C 
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

To get elements, just print `attributes(ItemsList)$intersections`:

```
> attributes(ItemsList)$intersections
$A
[1] "d"

$B
[1] "f"

$C
[1] "g"

$`A:B`
[1] "b"

$`A:C`
[1] "c"

$`B:C`
[1] "e"

$`A:B:C`
[1] "a"
```

Comment: Well OP didn't specify the type of output they require. So I assumed they only want the number of elements in each section of the Venn Diagram. If you plot the Venn Diagram using OPs given lists, you'll find that each section has exactly 1 element. Therefore I feel like that's what my output produce as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but Im looking for the names of the elements of the sub-lists. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper based on @itsDV7

```r
getVennOverlap <- function(lsvenn = list(A = sort(sample(LETTERS, 15)),
                                     B = sort(sample(LETTERS, 15)),
                                     C = sort(sample(LETTERS, 15)),
                                     D = sort(sample(LETTERS, 15)))
                           ) {
  
  ItemsList <- gplots::venn(lsvenn, show.plot = FALSE)
  print(lengths(attributes(ItemsList)$intersections))
  return(attributes(ItemsList)$intersections)
}
```

Test

```r
> getVennOverlap()
      A       B       D     A:B     A:C     A:D     B:C     B:D     C:D   A:B:C   A:B:D   A:C:D 
      1       1       1       1       2       1       3       1       1       1       3       3 
  B:C:D A:B:C:D 
      2       3 
$A
[1] "T"

$B
[1] "N"

$D
[1] "L"

$`A:B`
[1] "I"

...etc
```