# How to get list of unique items for each partition in venn diagram?

Tags: r

I've tried the code in this post: [Get the list of items in Venn diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559371/get-the-list-of-items-in-venn-diagram)

And while it does work in giving me the NUMBER of items that belong to each partition group, I cannot find a method that works in giving me a list of unique items for each partition (my venn diagram has 5 groups).

Here is a snippet of my data:

```
# Just to show the formatting of my input data
> str(d1)
 chr [1:438] "01100" "01110" "01120" "01200" "01210" "01212" "01230" "01250" "01240" "01220" "00010" "00020" "00030" ...

d1 <- c("01100", "01110", "01120", "01200", "01210", "01212", "01230", "01250", "01240")
d2 <- c("01100", "01110", "01120", "01200", "01210", "01240")
d3 <- c("01100", "01110", "01200", "01210", "01230", "01250", "01240", "01501")
d4 <- c("01100", "01200", "01210", "01212", "01230", "01250", "01240", "01501", "01503")
d5 <- c("01100", "01110", "01120", "01200", "01210", "01212", "01240", "05417")
```

Using the `get.venn.partitions` in VennDiagram only gives the counts of unique items belonging to each partition, but I would like to try and get a dataframe or list that shows what is unique in each partition. Something like:

```
> unique_to_d5
"05417"

> unique_to_d1
"None"

> unique_to_d4_d5
"01503" "05417"
```

I know the online program Venny (https://bioinfogp.cnb.csic.es/tools/venny/) can do something like this but sadly it doesn't go up to 5 categories, so I would need a list of all elements that belong to all 5 categories.

Comment: `VennDiagram::get.venn.partitions(d)` gives you the set, the values and the count. It does what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VennDiagram::get.venn.partitions` gives the unique values for each grouping in the venn diagram. I've also provided some additional data wrangling to get the output into a cleaner format.

```
library(VennDiagram)
library(tidyverse)

d <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5)
unique.partition <- VennDiagram::get.venn.partitions(d)
colnames(unique.partition) <-
  c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "set", "values", "count")

unique.partition %>%
  dplyr::mutate(values = ifelse(values == "character(0)", NA, values)) %>%
  tidyr::separate(set, c("set", "second"), sep = '\\s*[∖]\\s*') %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(second, d1:d5)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(set = gsub("[()]", "", set)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(set = gsub("[∩]", " ", set)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(set = str_replace_all(set, "X", "list_")) %>%
  dplyr::rename(Names = set,
                total = count,
                elements = values) %>%
  dplyr::filter(elements != "NA")
```

Output

```
                               Names                   elements total
1 list_1 list_2 list_3 list_4 list_5 01100, 01200, 01210, 01240     4
2               list_1 list_4 list_5                      01212     1
3        list_1 list_2 list_3 list_5                      01110     1
4               list_1 list_2 list_5                      01120     1
5                             list_5                      05417     1
6               list_1 list_3 list_4               01230, 01250     2
7                      list_3 list_4                      01501     1
8                             list_4                      01503     1
```

If you are needing the unique values for each group, then I would try to get the data into an easier format first before trying to get the unique values. Then, you can get the unique values for each of the 5 groups.

```
library(tidyverse)

lists <- list(d1 = d1, d2 = d2, d3 = d3, d4 = d4, d5 = d5)

data.frame(data = names(lists), number = matrix(lists)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c(number)) %>%
  dplyr::distinct(number, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   data  number
   <chr> <chr> 
 1 d1    01100 
 2 d1    01110 
 3 d1    01120 
 4 d1    01200 
 5 d1    01210 
 6 d1    01212 
 7 d1    01230 
 8 d1    01250 
 9 d1    01240 
10 d3    01501 
11 d4    01503 
12 d5    05417
```

Comment: This is not what is required. Please note that OP is looking for values only unique to each region

Comment: @Onyambu You're correct, I misinterpreted when I read it. I've updated my answer to include a new output with what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Yes this worked but I also did find another online (free) program that does exactly what Venny does. It gives the venn diagram output and list of unique terms per group in such a nice way. Here it is for anyone interested: http://bioinformatics.psb.ugent.be/webtools/Venn/

Comment: @CuriousDude I went ahead and did a little more data wrangling to get it into a more similar format to the website.

Answer (score 1):

Use set operations.

```
# d1u = d1 unique, d2u ...
d1u <- setdiff(d1, union(union(union(d2, d3), d4), d5))
d2u <- setdiff(d2, union(union(union(d1, d3), d4), d5))
d3u <- setdiff(d3, union(union(union(d2, d1), d4), d5))
d4u <- setdiff(d4, union(union(union(d2, d3), d1), d5))
d5u <- setdiff(d5, union(union(union(d2, d3), d4), d1))
```